# Angular 7 Material Sidenav fixed in viewport

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, angular-material, sidenav

I got a big problem using this example from material's [SideNav Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bbylpommldm?file=app%2Fsidenav-fixed-example.html)

I don't want my sidenav to overlap on my navbar/toolbar

here's my code

```
<mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" 

    [fixedInViewport]="false" 

    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false"

    >

  <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
  <mat-nav-list>
      <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" class="{{menuItem.class}} nav-item">
          <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" class="nav-link">

              {{menuItem.title}}
          </a>
      </li>
  </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
```

here's an image of it [image]

Comment: You can use mode="push"

Comment: in the example stackblitz, the sidenav is not overlapping the toolbar - can you update the code with your specific scenario?

Comment: What behavior are you aiming for: Do you want the `<mat-toolbar>` to be pushed to the side just like the content? Or do you want to it to be on top of the sidenav and never move (a real fixed header)? I believe the latter is what `<mat-toolbar>` is intended to be used like. Given that it's fixed by default

Comment: @Jojofoulk I want the latter, uminder I don't want it to push the toolbar, akber that's what I want

Comment: Get your  `<mat-toolbar>` outside the `<mat-sidenav>` or `<mat-sidenav-container>` if applicable, have it at the top of your html.

Comment: @Mark, Were you able to fix this issue? I'm not able to pull sidenav container below the mat-toolbar.

Comment: @BabyboB yes, I switched framework and used ng-bootstrap